# For a polynomial $p(x)$, value of $p(3)$ is $-2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

SAT prep problem. (I am not taking the SATs and so it is embarrassing that I can't solve this). 
Which of the following must be true about $p(x)$?

A. $x-5$ is a factor of $p(x)$

B. $x-2$ is a factor of $p(x)$

C. $x+2$ is a factor of $p(x)$

D. The remainder when $p(x)$is divided by $x-3$ is $-2$.

Since I don't what to do, I took an example. $p(x) = x^2 - 3x - 2$.

$p(3) = -2$

Then what?

Comment: Lookup the [polynomial remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem).

Comment: Thank the lord. I did say D was the answer. Kid said A. Now I had to re-ask and confirmed that the answer is indeed D. Alright. Sanity prevails. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If $p(3)=-2$ then $3$ will be the root of polynomial $g(x)=p(x)+2$ so $g(x)=(x-3)q(x)$. This leaves option $D$.

Comment: Agreed. The remainder theorem was what was needed. Thank you